# R code error : Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Could not resolve proxy: myproxy.server.com

Tags: r

I crawl web data in R.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
getwd()
body = c()
url = c()
url_base = "web address"

for(i in 1:4)
+ {
+     
+     url_crawl = paste(url_base, i , sep="")
+     b_css = "css code"
+     
+     hdoc = read_html(url_crawl)
+     
+     b_node = html_nodes(hdoc, b_css)
+     
+   }
```

> Error in `open.connection(x, "rb")` :    Could not resolve proxy:
>   `myproxy.server.com`

I used this code but now i can't use it. how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Can you provide a minimal example so we can test? It's very likely that you provide the wrong URL..

Comment: Absolutely not. URL is correct. I just used simple test, but it didn't work. I tried another URL but same debugging message. I think it's not URL address problem. what is proxy server problem in R?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that we can run?

Comment: put http://news.naver.com/main/ranking/popularDay.nhn?rankingType=popular_day&sectionId=105&date=201805 in "web address" and .nclicks\\(rnk\\.sci\\) in "css node" and edit code for(i in 10:28)

Comment: 1. I can read the web pages without any problems with the code you provide. 2. You used incorrect CSS. It should be something with your machine's local settings.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. This happens because my computer or program has a proxy server. So initialize. This code will be fine.

```
Sys.setenv("http_proxy"="")
Sys.setenv("no_proxy"=TRUE)
Sys.setenv("no_proxy"=1)
```